# WPF is not support bid unicode?

Tags: wpf, unicode, bidi

I have a WPF application.

I want to display Hebrew sentence that involved numbers and words.

I read about Unicode bidi and write little code for that as following:

```
 const string PDF = "\u202C"; 
 const string LRO = "\u202D"; 
 const string RLO = "\u202E"; 
 const string TEXT = "ערך ראשון : ערך שני";

 var parts = TEXT.Split(':');
 double number = -50;
 double number2 = -200;
 string str = string.Empty;

 str +=RLO + parts[0] + PDF;
 str +=LRO + number + PDF;
 str +=RLO + parts[1] + PDF;
 str +=LRO + shortValue + PDF;
 Text = str;
```

Now in xaml:

```
    <TextBlock Text="FlowDirection=LeftToRight TextAlignment=Right Language=he-IL" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Language="he-IL" TextAlignment="Right" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"/>

    <TextBlock Text="FlowDirection=LeftToRight TextAlignment=Left Language=he-IL" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" FlowDirection="LeftToRight"  Language="he-IL" TextAlignment="Left" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"/>

    <TextBlock Text="FlowDirection=RightToLeft TextAlignment=Left Language=he-IL" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" FlowDirection="RightToLeft"  Language="he-IL" TextAlignment="Left" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2"/>

    <TextBlock Text="FlowDirection=RightToLeft TextAlignment=Right Language=he-IL" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" FlowDirection="RightToLeft"  Language="he-IL" TextAlignment="Right" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3"/>
```

But it seems that it's not supported in WPF - as we can to see here:

[image]

The negative numbers doesn't designed proper..

Edit:

Thanks a lot to Hans Passant for his link.

I change the values of LRO and RLO to those:

```
    const string LRO = "\u200E";
    const string RLO = "\u200F";
```

And now it designed proper.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: And how would the expected result look like?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-to-left_mark

Comment: the expected result it that the minus sign should be left side of the numbers instead of being designed at right side.

Comment: @HansPassant, Thanks, your link is helps me:)

Answer (score 0):

You have to print numbers with the right culture. Right now you tell the program exactly how to write the string, and it does as you tell it to.

If you need some special number formatting, you have to use a [`Culture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/shxtf045%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

> ```
> double value = -16325.62015;
> // Display value using the invariant culture.
> Console.WriteLine(value.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
> // Display value using the en-GB culture.
> Console.WriteLine(value.ToString(CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB")));
> // Display value using the de-DE culture.
> Console.WriteLine(value.ToString(CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("de-DE")));
> ```

Comment: It's wpf - and this solution is not helps me. thanks